# html object not following parent

Tags: html, css

I have two sections in my website and as you can see in the code the div 'card3' is in the sec2 section but when using absolute position the object is apearing th the sec1

```
.card3 {width: var(--card3-width);
height: var(--card3-height);
z-index: 1;

border-radius: 1vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;

font-size: 1.5vh;
color: white;
align-self: center;
position: absolute;
top: 20vh;
right: 20vh;
transition: 1s ease-in-out;
border-width: 1vh;
background-image: linear-gradient(

 #5ddcff, #3c67e3 43%,#4e00c2);}
```

section 1 the blue figure is card3
[enter image description here][1]

html:

```
<section class="sec2" style="background-color:#0e1525 ; ">
    <div class="intro" id="intro" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;align-content: center;display: grid;grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;">
        <h1 style="margin-inline: auto;text-align: left;grid-row: 1;font-size: 10vh;font-family:'Roboto'; color: white;align-content: center;">Plants and Fire</h1>
    
        <p style="grid-row: 2;color: white;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;text-align: center;width: 80%;margin: auto;">
            Lorem ipsum, dolotrum?
        </p>
        
        
    </div>
    <div class="card3" id="car3">
            <h1>hello world</h1>
        </div>
</section>
```

section 2
[enter image description here][2]

the card3 must appear here
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrPEP.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xeY.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider adding `position:relative` to its parent element i.e. `.sec2`.

I'm not sure if you've provided enough info of your work but applying`position:absolute` to an element makes it positioned **relative to the nearest positioned ancestor**. Otherwise it will be positioned **relative to the document body.** [See more about position property here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).